# How to attach angular component to an third part application

Tags: angular, dynamic, web-component, angular-components

I would like to put my component in an application at runtime, and that would integrate with Angular.

I think a similar feature is:

1. Make a call with XHR
2. Put the response on a node with innerHtml

But, in the Angular way, that a component can integrate with the application, respond to lifecycles hooks, can react to click events and call a service.

Answer (score 0):

you use Angular web components for it which was introduced in Angular 6.0

Follow along the following tutorial 
https://medium.com/@tomsu/building-web-components-with-angular-elements-746cd2a38d5b

After creating web component elements,
we can use it like follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Custom Button Test Page</title>
  <script src="elements.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <custom-button label="First Value"></custom-button>

  <script>
    const button = document.querySelector('custom-button');
    button.addEventListener('action', (event) => {
      console.log(`"action" emitted: ${event.detail}`);
    })
    setTimeout(() => button.label = 'Second Value', 3000);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, I see I miss an important note, I've no access to source code. Think like I would like to put my component in Angular site.